# Is it possible to enable a Drupal module only on a specific Git branch?

Tags: git, drupal-7

I would like if possible to only enable the Drupal metatags module on a specific Git branch. Is this possible, and please can someone point me in the direction of how to go about this if so?  I assume I'll need to add something to the config.inc file?

Thank you.

Comment: If a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about drupal, I suppose this is more a question on git, rather than on drupal. Just change to the git branch you desire and add the drupal metatags module to git there but make damn sure you don't merge this branch to any other git branch. This is the quick and dirty solution.

Comment: It's enabled on my current branch, but I may need to switch to others during development and I don't want it to come onto those branches.

Comment: Then just don't do `git merge`. This will not happen out of nowhere.